# ORACLE return from function without creating a new type

Tags: oracle, function, types, oracle11g, return

I'm wanting to create a function (oracle 11g) that will return multiple values but without having to creating a new TYPE.  The end goal is much more complicated than the example I'm providing, but I can do pretty much everything else except get the values to return.

Here is an extremely simplified version of what I'm having trouble with.

for example given the following table (employees):

```
emplid | emplname | emplchildren
478    |SAM       |"GEORGE,RON"
479    |JOSE      |"RICHARD,JANE,RACHEL"
480    |PAM       |"JORDAN"
```

I would like the following statement `select CHILD_FN from employees` to return:

```
GEORGE
RON
RIRCHARD
JANE
RACHEL
JORDAN
```

This is simplified to show the part I'm having trouble with
Here is a sample code:

```
create or replace function CHILD_FN RETURN employee.emplname%TYPE IS
    chldnames employee.emplname%TYPE;

CURSOR child_cur
IS 
Select emplchildren FROM employees;


  begin

      /*do complicated parsing to separate each delimited 
       value of child_cur and assign
       it to a new row in the names_col variable/

      /*how do I add values to the names_col variable?  I've tried
      'chldnames.extend',
      various types of 'bulk collect into chldnames'
      and they all give various errors*/


      return chldnames;

end LOCAL_TEST_FN;
```

do I need to change my return type, or is it not declared properly?
I'm not completely against created a new type in the database, it's just we've gotten very far without ever having to create a new type, and the less complicated I can make things, the better. And if there is a way around it, I would prefer to learn that way and make the decision on which is better.

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are many pre-defined collections that can be useful.  For example, I generally use sys.odciVarchar2List, a VARRAY(32767) OF VARCHAR2(4000).  But usually only for adhoc code.  For production code you're probably better off creating your own types.  It will make things more clear and  is less likely to cause problems if someone decides to revoke access to standard objects.

```
create or replace function child_fn return sys.odcivarchar2list is
    childnames sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
begin
    --Add elements
    childnames.extend;
    childnames(childnames.last) := 'GEORGE';
    childnames.extend;
    childnames(childnames.last) := 'RON';
    --...

    --Also could use something like this:
    --childnames := sys.odciVarchar2List('GEORGE','RON','RIRCHARD','JANE');

    return childnames;
end;
/

--For SQL it's often more convenient to use it like a table:
select column_value from table(child_fn);
```